# Hair Particle Creates Spikes Instead of Hair in Cycles Blender 3.0

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

I am using Blender 3.0, I need help to fix my problem. It happen when I add hair particle system to a plane and it is creates a spikes/cones instead of hairs.

- I am using CPU for rendering
- My device CPU is Ryzen 3 8 threads
- Windows 11 Pro Operating System 64bit
- GPU Radeon RX 570

[image: Hair particlesystem creates a spikes instead a hairs]

Comment: It would be helpful if your screenshot showed more of the hair settings, especially the settings for _Hair Shape_.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you apply the plane's scale, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> *Apply > Scale*